# How to reset .profile in Linux Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, .profile

I'm running Linux Mint 19 Bionic, and I messed around with the .profile to do some custom stuff. While it all works it triggers a warning about errors in the script. After figuring out that the task I want to to do contradicts with the features of .profile, I can't seem to get it back to how it was. Is there a way I can reset the .profile to the default settings?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/381340/how-to-reset-profile-to-default

Comment: Thanks. I could swear I had tried that and it hadn't worked but I just tried and it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a whole new user, then copy over whatever default files you want from their home into yours. (Logging in once as the new user *might* change or initialize a few things).

Or go directly to `/etc/skel` and copy whatever default files you want from there.